# Android Convert Large view to bitmap

Tags: android, image, android-layout

I need to convert large views say(width and height as 1280x1760) to Bitmap and save the image to sdcard.But When i create views more than of size 1280x1400 my application is throwing an Exception wnen createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache()) is called.I am using 10 inch samsung tab.
Does image pixel depend on tab pixel
here is my code

```
 View   view2=LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.sample, null);

             LinearLayout   view=new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
              view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);  
              view.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
             view.addView(view2,new LayoutParams(1280,1760));


              view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);


             view.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), 
                    MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

              view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight()); 

              view.buildDrawingCache(true);
           try{
              Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
              //Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(view.getDrawingCache(), 1280, 1200, true);


              //setContentView(view);   
              String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Pictures";     

                          File image = new File(path, "Image7.jpg");

                          // Encode the file as a PNG image.
                          FileOutputStream outStream=null;


                              outStream = new FileOutputStream(image);
                              bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream); 

                              outStream.flush();
                              outStream.close();

                                   setContentView(view);
                          } catch (Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), 10).show();

                      }
```

and sample.xml layout is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300px"
        android:text="TextView" 
        android:background="#ffff00"/>

    <Button android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/button1"  android:background="#ff00ff"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Button" />

   <Button android:layout_weight="1"  android:background="#ff0000"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

here is the LOGCAT

```
01-21 14:26:50.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1611): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-21 14:26:50.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1611): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-21 14:26:50.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1611):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:455)
01-21 14:26:50.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1611):     at com.hunterlab.essentials.view2image.View2ImageActivity$1.Check(View2ImageActivity.java:196)
01-21 14:26:50.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1611):     at com.hunterlab.essentials.view2image.View2ImageActivity$1.onClick(View2ImageActivity.java:79)
01-21 14:26:50.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1611):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3110)
01-21 14:26:50.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1611):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:11928)
01-21 14:26:50.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1611):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-21 14:26:50.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1611):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-21 14:26:50.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1611):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
01-21 14:26:50.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1611):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)
01-21 14:26:50.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1611):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-21 14:26:50.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1611):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
01-21 14:26:50.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1611):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
01-21 14:26:50.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1611):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
01-21 14:26:50.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1611):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please find the logcat above i think problem is with view.getDrawingCache() which returns null

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (which will work even if they view has disabled its drawing cache):

```
int width = view.getWidth();
int height = view.getHeight();
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
view.draw(canvas);
// The view has now drawn to `bitmap`
```

Comment: I already tried the above code it worked to create bitmap of desired size but how to draw whole view to bitmap.....that the main problem

Comment: please some one can tell me how to draw whole view of size(1280x1760) to Bitmap . Or is there any other approach to convert whole view to Bitmap.........please respond

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please have a look at this code.

```
public static Bitmap new_decode(File f) {

    // decode image size

    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    o.inDither = false; // Disable Dithering mode

    o.inPurgeable = true; // Tell to gc that whether it needs free memory,
                            // the Bitmap can be cleared

    o.inInputShareable = true; // Which kind of reference will be used to
                                // recover the Bitmap data after being
                                // clear, when it will be used in the future
    try {
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
    final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 300;
    int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
    int scale = 1;
    while (true) {
        if (width_tmp / 1.5 < REQUIRED_SIZE && height_tmp / 1.5 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
            break;
        width_tmp /= 1.5;
        height_tmp /= 1.5;
        scale *= 1.5;
    }

    // decode with inSampleSize
    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    // o2.inSampleSize=scale;
    o.inDither = false; // Disable Dithering mode

    o.inPurgeable = true; // Tell to gc that whether it needs free memory,
                            // the Bitmap can be cleared

    o.inInputShareable = true; // Which kind of reference will be used to
                                // recover the Bitmap data after being
                                // clear, when it will be used in the future
    // return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    try {

//      return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null,
//              null);
        Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, null);
        System.out.println(" IW " + width_tmp); 
        System.out.println("IHH " + height_tmp);           
        //   int iW = width_tmp;
         //   int iH = height_tmp;
       int iW = Talk_Library.screen_width;
        int iH = Talk_Library.screen_height;


           return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, iW, iH, true);

    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
        // clearCache();

        // System.out.println("bitmap creating success");
        System.gc();
        return null;
        // System.runFinalization();
        // Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
        // System.gc();
        // decodeFile(f);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

}
```